# How to change fencing coordinators on symantec sfs

Tags: nas, symantec

The following the the steps that I think would work... please correct me I am wrong.

1. add three new disks/luns to the sfs
2. scanbus
3. replace the fencing disks (#storage fencing change ,,)
4. take out the old fencing disks/luns

I am not sure if I need to turn fencing off before replacing the fencing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use the replace command as I heard it could some issues.

The following are the steps I followed

1. Add new disks/luns to the sfs
2. scanbus
3. Turn fencing off
4. destroy the old fencing disk
5. turn the fencing on with the new disks